# Aloe Vera leaning to one side

Tags: flowers

Why is my Aloe Vera leaning to one side? I tried to pull it straight and it seems like it's working for the upper part like you can see in the photo.
Can I just cut it's bottom leaves and fill the pot with soil?
[image][image]

Comment: Just came to say that is one Beautiful Aloe Vera. make sure you take good care of this beautiful specimen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kid mentioned plants grow towards the light.  For this reason, make sure you turn your pot weekly a 1/4 or 1/2 turn.   This will provide you plant equal light on all sides.

I would suggest starting with a taller stake, rather than putting more soil in the pot.  More soil means more moisture.  Longer it takes for your plant to dry out.  But, yes you can remove the leaves and bury the plant deeper.  I would not recommend you do it.  Your soil does appear to hold lots of water.

Other than the leaning this is an amazing specimen.  You have a beautiful plant.

Answer (score 2):

-->Usually plants propagates in the direction of sunlight. if there is no equal distribution of light on the plant this might be one of the reason.

--> you might be watering plant from one side of the plant so plants leans towards wet side.